# How to control unrelated circuit with a transistor?

Tags: transistors, source, isolated

I recently hit this issue that seems to be too complicated for google to find results for.

Is it possible to control a different circuit with a transistor from a separate circuit?

Below is a simplified schematic for what I mean.

Lets say that the transistor is controlled by some sort of a complicated power source, not a battery, but a USB port or usb power bank or a switching power supply, and the transistor is supposed to switch a different separated circuit with its own separate power source of a different voltage.

Is that possible without connecting the two circuits together?

I think it is not, but I do not know the theory behind it.
If it is not possible, how is this problem usually solved without a relay, if there is a way?

[image]

Comment: Just a comment, you can use relay instead of transistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, it would be fine to connect the ground wires in the circuit you show.  You have two battery powered supplies, so nothing bad will happen if you connect the circuits together.

If you really needed for the two circuits to be electrically separated, then you could use an optocoupler.  That could be needed if one of the power supplies is not isolated from the line voltage.

Do not do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnqTYA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That has the battery powered side connected to directly to the outlet.

Neutral is supposed to be safe, but you cannot guarantee that the wire you intended to be on neutral is really neutral.

The whole circuit has to be handled as if it were at 240VAC - including all parts of the battery and button.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9n30H.png)</sup>

With the optocoupler circuit, there's no electrical connection between the battery and the neutral.  The battery side of the circuit is safe to handle.

An optocoupler is a photodiode and phototransistor in one package.  They are separated from one another by a small gap such that the light from the photodiode can trigger the phototransistor, but no current can jump the gap.  They are usually specified to withstand a thousand volts or so.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use an opto-isolator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSWpe2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An opto-isolator uses an infra-red LED and a photo-transistor encapsulated in the one package. They provide complete electrical isolation between the control circuit and the load circuit - typically up to 4000 V.

I've written more about them [here](https://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-isolators/).

Comment: Thank you very much.